# How do you write an elisp lambda to provide an argument to save-some-buffers?

Tags: lambda, elisp

I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
(global-set-key [f7] (lambda (save-some-buffers t)))
```

Which is that [f7] saves all file buffers without asking me any questions.  Problem is I don't know how to express the lambda so that can provide the option for save-some-buffers.

```
save-some-buffers is an interactive compiled Lisp function.

It is bound to C-x s.

(save-some-buffers &optional ARG PRED)

Save some modified file-visiting buffers.  Asks user about each one.
You can answer `y' to save, `n' not to save, `C-r' to look at the
buffer in question with `view-buffer' before deciding or `d' to
view the differences using `diff-buffer-with-file'.

This command first saves any buffers where `buffer-save-without-query' is
non-nil, without asking.

Optional argument (the prefix) non-nil means save all with no questions.
Optional second argument PRED determines which buffers are considered:
If PRED is nil, all the file-visiting buffers are considered.
If PRED is t, then certain non-file buffers will also be considered.
If PRED is a zero-argument function, it indicates for each buffer whether
to consider it or not when called with that buffer current.

See `save-some-buffers-action-alist' if you want to
change the additional actions you can take on files.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are missing: the argument list (which will be empty in this case), and an `interactive` declaration, without which Emacs won't let you call the function from a key binding.

```
(global-set-key [f7] (lambda () (interactive) (save-some-buffers t)))
```